# Check if NSSize is nil - Comparing non-optional value of type 'NSSize'?

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

I have a NSSize variable

```
var originalselectedimagesize:NSSize

if(originalselectedimagesize == nil)
{
}
```

I'm trying to check if NSSize is set ? But i keep getting the following warning.How can i check if the value of NSSize is changed?

```
h(aka 'CGSize') to 'nil' always returns false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because from the declaration, NSSize is not an optional. So checking a non-optional value for nil always return false.

In case if you have the following, then you won't get the warning.

```
var originalselectedimagesize:NSSize?

if(originalselectedimagesize == nil)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare `originalselectedimagesize` as `NSSize?` (`Optional` type of `NSSize`), and set it to `nil`. Then, you can check if it has value like this:

```swift
var originalselectedimagesize: NSSize? = nil

// what ever...

// check for value
if let size = originalselectedimagesize {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Is there a need to initialise it to null ? btw i did not downvote your answer.